# JFrame losing its structure and looks on resizing after button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the following code to run a simple number guessing program on the click of a button:

```
public class test3 implements ActionListener {

public void create()
{
    Dimension s=new Dimension(400,400);
    JFrame l=new JFrame();

    l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    l.setSize(s);
    l.setResizable(true);
    Dimension s1=new Dimension(400,200);

    JPanel me=new JPanel(); 
    JPanel ne=new JPanel();

    JLabel kingsman=new JLabel ("GUESS THE KING'S NUMBER!");
    kingsman.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 45));

    JPanel common=new JPanel();
    BoxLayout n1=new BoxLayout(common,1);
    common.setLayout(n1);

    JButton p=new JButton("START"); 
    p.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
    p.setPreferredSize(s1);
    //l.add(p);
    me.add(kingsman);
    ne.add(p);

    common.add(me);
    common.add(ne);
    l.add(common);
   // l.pack();
    l.setVisible(true);
    p.addActionListener(this); 

}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");
        gamer2 game=new gamer2();
        game.generatenum();
    }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    test3 ob=new test3();
    ob.create();

}

}
```

[image: This is how the JFrame looks initially]

But on clicking the button,the JFrame deteriorates:
[image: This is how it looks after clicking the button(on resizing).]

The JFrame also refuses to close when the button is clicked even though `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` is mentioned.But it closes if I don't click the button.

`generatenum` function in class `gamer2`:

```
void generatenum()
    {
        int ran=(int)(Math.random()*10);
        System.out.println("For developer-no.selected "+ran);
        gamer3 ob1=new gamer3(); //gamer3 takes user input
        ob1.getUserInput(ran);

    }
```

Can someone explain me what is actually going wrong?I have been trying to crack it but nothing has helped me so far.
The event handling part is working perfectly.On clicking the button,`generatenum()` runs successfully.Th rest of the programs works on the `Eclipse console`.

- I understand that JFrame does not close till the complete program gets executed,but in this case,the rest of the program is not dependent on JFrame.Is it refusing to close because the object of `gamer2` is created within the action handling method which exists only if JFrame exists?
- The JFrame is only changing it's looks when I resize it.Resizing it destroys the looks but this doesn't occur if the button is not yet clicked.

Class `gamer3` (accepting user input):

```
public class gamer3 {
    int getIt; int gotValue; static int i=0;

    gamer1 l=new gamer1();
    static gamer3 g=new gamer3();

    void getUserInput(int k)
    {

        i++;
        System.out.println("print now-Chance "+i);

        g.gotValue=k;
        InputStreamReader j=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader s=new BufferedReader(j);
        try {
            int getIt1=Integer.parseInt(s.readLine());

            g.getIt=getIt1;
        }  catch (IOException e) 
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
            }

        l.checker(g.getIt,g.gotValue );
    }
```

Class `gamer1`:

```
static int trial=0; int result=0; int value=0; String d;
    public void checker(int get,int craze)
    {
        value=get;
        result=craze;
        ++trial;
       if(value==result)
       {
           System.out.println("Successful");
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println("wrong entry");
           if(trial<=3)
           {
               int c=3;
               int rem=c-trial;
               System.out.println("You have " +rem+ " chance(s) left!");


            if(trial<3)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter y to play again or n to exit!");
                   System.out.println("D you want to retry?_");
                   InputStreamReader k =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                   BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(k);
                    try {
                        d= read.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                if(d.equals("y"))
                {
                    d="null";

                    gamer3 mele=new gamer3();
                    mele.getUserInput(result);
                }

            }   


           }



               else
               {
                   System.out.println("you are out of the game.No chances left!");
               }
       }

    }

    }
```

Class gamer2:

```
package test;
public class gamer2 {
int getIt;
//complete generation of the goddamn random number
void generatenum()
{
    int ran=(int)(Math.random()*10);
    System.out.println("For developer-no.selected "+ran);
    gamer3 ob1=new gamer3();
    ob1.getUserInput(ran);

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");
gamer2 newj=new gamer2();
newj.generatenum();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `getUserInput` and other methods that it calls?

Comment: Yes....I'll just edit the question to add that. @Sweeper

Comment: @Sweeper I have a problem with the JFrame only.The game is working well and the JFrame closes when the game execution is completed.But why is it changing in looks on minimizing and maximizing again (after button click)?....It keeps changing in looks each time I minimize and maximize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread by trying to read user input from the console.

This is just a horribly bad idea, see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

GUI's are event driven environments, that is, something happens and you respond to it.  Console programs tend to be far more linear in nature.  It's not a good idea to mix them.

If you're using a GUI, get your input from the user via the GUI. Take a closer look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot!..I got it now.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as the default close operation.

Also try implementing the `WindowListener` interface like this:

```
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I am new to java GUI.Can you add a bit of explanation?

Comment: @MathewsMathai He basically tells you to set the default close operation to something else. And add `implements WindowListener` in the class declaration, and add the method in his answer.

Comment: Okay.Got it.I'll try that.But the thing is what is actually going wrong with my code.
@Sweeper

Comment: @Binoy Cherian Can you add an explanation on what is wrong with my code and why is the JFrame getting deteriorated on minimizing after the button click?...That is kind of weird and I can't find this issue anywhere else on the internet.

Comment: `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is doing EXACTLY which you've just described, but with a lot less code (in fact it's the reason it exists).  It was little to do with the actual problem the OP is having