# Button not removed until complete program is executed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a button which runs a function in another class.The button click event handling goes like this:

```
    JPanel ne=new JPanel();
    JButton startButton=new JButton("START"); 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

        ne.remove(startButton);
        gamer2 game=new gamer2();
        game.generatenum();

    }
```

The JButton `startButton` is added to a JPanel `ne`.Once the button is clicked,`actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` runs and the button is supposed to be removed from the JPanel.But the button remains there until the whole program finishes running.Can someone help me with this?

Complete code for the JFrame:

```
package test;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class test3 implements ActionListener {

    JButton p=new JButton("START"); 
    JPanel ne=new JPanel();

    public void create()
    {
        Dimension s=new Dimension(400,400);
        JFrame l=new JFrame();

        l.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        l.setSize(s);
        l.setResizable(true);
        Dimension s1=new Dimension(400,200);
        Dimension s2=new Dimension(400,100);

        JPanel me=new JPanel(); 


        JLabel kingsman=new JLabel ("GUESS THE KING'S NUMBER!");
        kingsman.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 45));

        JPanel commonPane=new JPanel();
        BoxLayout n1=new BoxLayout(commonPane,1);
        commonPane.setLayout(n1);


        p.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
        p.setPreferredSize(s1);
        JTextField tf=new JTextField();
        tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 45));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5);
        tf.setBorder(border);
        tf.setPreferredSize(s2);
        JPanel cn=new JPanel();
        cn.add(tf);
        //l.add(p);
        me.add(kingsman);
        ne.add(p);

        commonPane.add(me);
        commonPane.add(ne);
        commonPane.add(cn);
        l.add(commonPane);

        l.setVisible(true);
        p.addActionListener(this); 

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
        System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

        ne.remove(p);

        ne.updateUI();
        gamer2 game=new gamer2();
        game.generatenum();

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        test3 ob=new test3();
        ob.create();

    }

}
```

Comment: Just a tip, it makes it a lot easier for other programmers to help you when you name your variables more descriptively. It doesn't take much longer to type `startButton` vs `p`, especially with auto-completion in modern IDEs, and it's much more descriptive. You may even help yourself when debugging.

Comment: Okay.I'll do that.editing.

Comment: all of the solutions work perfectly but only after the complete program is executed..

Comment: Can you show the Code where you add the Button?

Comment: @hinneLinks I have edited the post to add all the code for the JFrame.

Comment: To those who feel that I am seeking debugging help,I have debugged this program several times but still the root of the cause is not visible.

Comment: This has the entire code for the program:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479318/jframe-losing-its-structure-and-looks-on-resizing-after-button-click/34479425#34479425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the updates on the GUI (initiated by `ne.remove(p);` and `ne.updateUI();`) will be done **after** the `actionPerformed(..)` method finishes. Therefore `game.generatenum();` should only bring up the new GUI and return as fast as possible.

Comment: Now that makes sense.But why isn't executed when the line is encountered??

Comment: First the changes should be made and then `game.generatenum()` should be executed..right??...According to the flow of lines?

Comment: That is the way swing has been designed. The `updateUI` method schedules a repaint event on the event queue. This event will be handled after the current event (button click -> `actionPerformed(..)`) has been handled.

Comment: Thanks a lot.So How do I make changes to the frame before `game.generatenum()` is executed?

Comment: As others have pointed out it is a horrible idea to mix a Swing GUI with Console input. The proper way to go would be to implement gamer2 / gamer3 with Swing too. An "easy" way out could be to run `game.generatenum();` in a new thread. Easy in quotes because it further complicates your design.

Comment: Okay.Basically,clicking the button again restarts the program so I wanted the button to be removed till one session is complete.I'll probably convert everything to GUI.

Comment: What does `creating a new thread` mean?...Can you throw some light on that?

Comment: @MathewsMathai You could code it like this (on one line since there is no better formatting in a comment): `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { gamer2 game=new gamer2(); game.generatenum(); }}).start();`. But - this road leads to the next problem: how to reenable the button once your console part finishes...

Comment: Okay.That means I need to go through the complete GUI topic and the related topics.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances, something like...

```
ne.remove(startButton);
ne.revalidate();
ne.repaint();
```

should work.  If this doesn't work, that would suggest that you're doing something else wrong in your code which you're not showing us and you should consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

So having look at the source code, I updated the `actionPeformed` method to look like...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Guess the number Game");
    System.out.println("You have 3 chances to guess a number between 0 and 10 excluding 10");

    ne.remove(p);
    ne.revalidate();
    ne.repaint();

    //ne.updateUI();
    //gamer2 game = new gamer2();
    //game.generatenum();

}
```

And that worked fine for me.

I would, however, encourage you to have a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a better alternative

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire program?

Comment: As I said, we want a runnable "example" which demonstrates you problem, which is NOT a code dump. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details about what we're looking for

Comment: @MathewsMathai Updated your code and it runs fine for me, see updates

Comment: Yes..I did that too.By commenting off those lines,the program completes execution which yet again proves the fact that the JFrame can be modified if the program completes running.

Comment: But the use of my button is to run the `generatenum()` function in class `gamer2`.If I remove those 2 lines,the button is useless.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have the source code for `gamer2`, so I couldn't run your example with it, so I took it out, my attention was focused on fixing it so that the button would disappear from the window.  If the button is still visible when you re-enable those two lines (ignore `updateUI`, you should never use it), then you have a bigger problem which is not demonstrated with the code you've provided

Comment: May I provide you a link to an earlier question I asked which has the entire code for the program??...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34479318/jframe-losing-its-structure-and-looks-on-resizing-after-button-click/34479425#34479425

Comment: Okay, so based on your previous code, you're accepting user input from the console from within a GUI, this is a recipe for disaster, which you've discovered.  GUI's a event driven frameworks, that is, something happens and you respond to it, they are NOT linear in nature. Console programs are linear. The way you appear to have your code setup, suggests that while you're waiting for user input, the GUI thread (AKA The Event Dispatching Thread) is been blocked, meaning it can't respond to new events, including repaint events, so your UI won't update

Comment: Is there a solution to this?..>How can I achieve this requirement?
And is this EDT thing mentioned in java API?

Comment: The EDT is the thread in which the GUI runs (events are dispatched to components), if you block this thread for any reason, no more events get dispatched, including paint events. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  The solution is not to get user input from the console in this way, but instead, use the GUI to get the input you need. See [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more options

Comment: Okay.Thanks a lot.Got it.

Answer (score 1):

After removing the button, revalidate the UI, then repaint it.

```
ne.revalidate();
ne.repaint();
```

This should invalidate the UI and request that it be redrawn.

Comment: That's not working.Should I revalidate() the JFrame too??...Since I have multiple JPanels in the JFrame.

Comment: @MathewsMathai Edited, try again :)

Comment: @MitchTalmadge It's not just the button.I am not able to make any dynamic changes to the frame.Even resizing isn't working properly.

Comment: @MathewsMathai To me, that last comment suggests that the reference of the frame you're working with is NOT the one which is on the screen

Answer (score 0):

You can call the UI update method,

```
en.updateUI();
```

This will update all the UI inside this `JPanel`.

Comment: This didn't work.I have three JPanels in the same JFrame.Is that the issue?

Comment: No, it is no problem if you have multiple JPanels in a JFrame

Comment: Where did you add the start button to JPanel ne?

Comment: @MathewsMathai For your resizing issue, you need to do ne.pack()

Comment: If you ever find yourself having to use `updateUI`, then you've done something horribly wrong

Comment: Yes.The button removes successfully once the entire program is executed.I am not able to make on the fly changes to the JFrame.

Comment: I still using updateUI(), in my program, otherwise if I add or remove any child from JPanel it is not going be updated by repaint or other method, Only updateUI method work well here.